# jquery slidetoggle where show/hide links are different

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Here is the code I'm using (found elsewhere on this site) for a pretty straight-forward slideToggle.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();

        $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("fast");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section-hold">
    <h4>Section</h4>
    <p><a href="#" class="show_hide">find out more >></a></p>       
</div>

<div class="slidingDiv">            
    <h4>My content.</p>
</div>
```

What I would like though is for when I click to show the slidingDiv, my "find out more" link disappears and the toggle to hide the slidingDiv content is a different link, contained within that div itself.  So the HTML would become something like this:

```
<div class="section-hold">
    <h4>Section</h4>
    <p><a href="#" class="show">find out more >></a></p>        
</div>

<div class="slidingDiv">            
    <h4>My content.</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="hide">close this section</a></p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish that?  Note that there are also a couple sections on this page so ideally the code would be reusable to do this several times on the page.

I'm currently using jQuery 1.11.0 if it makes a difference.

Thanks so much.

Comment: In your last code block example, shouldn't `<p><a href="#" class="show">find out more >></a></p> ` be removed?

Comment: The example was to show what the HTML would look like, so through javascript the class="show" wouldn't be visible but class="hide" would be (assuming that .slidingDiv was visible). Hope that clarifies, thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to hide .section-hold when .slidingDiv is visible? So toggle between each div being displayed?

Comment: No, .section-hold should still be visible, just class="show" (find out more) should not be visible.

Comment: @user5710 I've posted an answer. Hopefully it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for. I've coded it so it should be reusable on the same page.

Firstly (to help with the re-usability), wrap your html in another `<div>` so you have:

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="section-hold">
        <h4>Section</h4>
        <p><a href="#" class="show">find out more >></a></p>        
    </div>

    <div class="slidingDiv">            
        <h4>My content.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="hide">close this section</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need a function to show the `.slidingDiv` while also hiding the `.show` link which you have just clicked on.

```
$('.show').click(function (e) {
    var slider = $(this).closest('.sliderContainer').find('.slidingDiv');
    slider.show('slide');
    $(this).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This uses the extra `<div>` I added in order to find the related `.slidingDiv` so that you can use this safely elsewhere on the page.

You then need a function to hide the `.slidingDiv` and then show the `.show` link again. So like this:

```
$('.hide').click(function (e) {
    var slider = $(this).closest('.slidingDiv');
    slider.hide('slide');
    $('.show').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And that should be it. Here is a jsfiddle of the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/d9UeL/

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is actually working really well, thanks so much. One question to ask is whether it's possible to slide down rather than slide in from the side?

Comment: @user5710 It does slide down for me! Which is the default. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @user5710 It is possible to do it with slideDown() and slideUp() instead of hide('slide') and show('slide') though if you're having trouble. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d9UeL/1/

Comment: Ya it was sliding in from the left for me but your most recent slideDown and slideUp works like a charm.  Thanks again.